# Error importing Polygon from shapely.geometry.polygon

Tags: python, python-import, shapely

In my Anaconda 2.2 64bit with Python 3.4.3 the following line works well:

```
import shapely
```

But the following line:

```
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
```

returns the following error:

```
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I tried with iNotebook, idle.exe and Eclipse. They all use Anaconda (the only Python installation on my computer) and they all show the same error.

If I type `from shapely.geometry import Polygon` in Eclipse, then I click on `Polygon`, then I press `F3`, Eclipse is able to open the module `C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\polygon.py`. So Eclipse is able to find it, but the execution fails.

**EDIT 2**

I just tried the same import on another computer with similar configuration and it works. The "only" difference between the two computers is that one has Windows 7 (it works) and one has Windows 8 (it doesn't).

I installed Anaconda and a few packages in both the computers following the same old checklist. The computer with Windows 8 can see the package from Eclipse, but can't import it.

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar problem and it was due to the way that I improperly installed shapely (although this was on a Windows 7 machine, not Windows 8).  For the initial install under which I couldn't import the `geometry` sub-module I installed shapely with the command:

```
pip install shapely
```

However after reading the documentation [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) more closely I saw that for Windows an executable installer needed to be used.  That installer is a wheel file that needs to be launched by pip as well.  So I uninstalled the first version of shapely with:

```
pip uninstall shapely
```

Then I launched the installer via the wheel file like this:

```
pip install your/file/path/Shapely‑1.5.9‑cp27‑none‑win32.whl
```

Note that you must [download](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely) the wheel that matches the specs of the version of python that your applying the package to.  I have 32-bit (`win32`) python 2.7 (`p27`) so the package above was the correct one.  Note that the reference to 32 or 64 bit in the file name refers to the version of python, not to the version of windows.

Comment: Thanks, but I gave up with Windows 8. I'm back with Windows 7, where the same identical installation steps work well.

Comment: Did it but says: sfepy-2018.1-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform. How can I fix it? also tried with amd64

Answer (score 9):

Try with below one, it solved the issue for me (Windows 10):

```
conda install -c conda-forge shapely
```

[shapely package docs](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/shapely)

Comment: I don't have the admin credentials with me. So this command fails in the last step

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
```

That's how the docs list it:
http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#polygons

Comment: I get the same error message (that is the tutorial I am following now to learn how to use shapely, I added the `.polygon` after Eclipse suggested me the import)

Comment: Are you running this through some sort of editor (Eclipse)?  Does the editor use anaconda as its interpreter?

Comment: I tried with iNotebook, idle.exe and Eclipse. They all use Anaconda (the only Python installationon my pc) and they all show the same error.

Comment: Maybe you need to install shapely - have you done so?  (http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/pkg-docs.html, https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use anything but Python version 3.7. Download it now!

Then go to PyCharm (that's what I'm using) and open it, then download the file for your specific version (from here https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#shapely) mine is *Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl* (this is respectively version 3.7 (37) and Windows (64) as seen above)

Now with your newly downloaded file, copy and paste it into where you are working from in PyCharm's folder location. For me this is: *C:\Users\lewis\PycharmProjects\Project1\NewProject*

Then you should see the newly copied file in PyCharm itself as well as where you put it.

Now right click the file in PyCharm *Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl*
and click *OPEN IN TERMINAL* then type:

```
pip install Shapely-1.6.4.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

It should say "successful".

Then go into your working area and type:

```
from shapely.geometry import point
```

Run it. It should now work for all!

Be in mind that this will ONLY allow for the importing of Shapely in this one environment. So you'll have to copy the Shapely file into new folder locations if you use in other places.

Specs:
Be in mind I am working with a Windows 10, Python interpreter version 37, PyCharm, Virutalenv environment type. Also, make sure in the settings you are indeed in the Python 37 interpreter and not in a conda environment.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and make it more readable? Use `typewriter font` with backticks (\`), use paragraphs for a better overview and don't use phrases like "I know how to fix this!!!", because that's needless. Your are posting an answer, you should know it! Also, don't write everything in upper case or bold.

Comment: Hey im saying "I know how to fix this!!!" because ive tried and tested what everyone has said and none of them have worked. mine is tested because i was literally was trying to do it myself for about a week.